# Install Numpy compiled for VS2010 for an embedded interpreter

Tags: c++, python, compilation, numpy

Another of my queries about an embedded Python 2.7.3 interpreter on Windows.  I need to install numpy and matplotlib as support packages for an embedded interpreter in a C++ program compiled in Visual Studio 2010.

**Some background:**

I've been trying to make this work for a few months.  The main issue is that numpy for Python 2.7 is compiled against an earlier version of the MS C library (VS2008) whereas my application is compiled against the 2010 version (a fact beyond my control - that is the office compiler).
I worked around this by fiddling with the manifest for my application to let it load the correct C library for numpy and this got it to import.  As an end-user has tried out new features, bugs have started to appear, including untraceable crashes.

**My current state:**

I pinned some of these down to a poor compilation on my part of the Python 2.7.3 source, in particular the dependencies (lots of the crashes seemed associated with Tkinter from matplotlib).  So I started afresh on the Python compilation and now have a clean compiled version of all the core and dependencies of Python 2.7.3.  Now I'm looking at numpy/matplotlib.

**My questions**

Is it worth attempting to compile numpy against VS2010 or is my earlier manifest mangling solution the only way?

If the former, what problems might I encounter in doing so (i.e. what should I watch ou for)?

In the latter, how do I get numpy to install in the lib/site-packages folder of my embedded intepreter?

Comment: I believe you will need a fortran compiler to compile numpy. You can probably use MinGW's g77 or gfortran. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/install.html

Comment: @codeape:  Thanks for this - I was aware I'd need one, but was obsessed with getting the C compiler aspect to be compatible.  Thanks for the reminder though!

Comment: Christoph Gohlke has alternative numpy Windows packages. Perhaps they're built using VS 2010. http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Comment: @codeape: I've looked at those, but I can't install them to examine them using hte Dependency Walker because the installer can't find a Python 2.7 installation (there isn't one as the interpreter is embedded).  Hence the last part of my question.

Comment: @codeape:  just tried it on a different machine - Gohlke's packages appear to be compiled against VS2008, not VS2010

Comment: You don't need to use the installer, you can unzip the exe installer files to have a look at the files inside, and manually copy them to somewhere on your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Gohlke could be persuaded to either 1) Build a numpy on VS2010 or 2) Offer detailed instructions on how to set up a Windows numpy build environment. His contact details: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/

Comment: @codeape:  none of my unzip programs would recognise Gohlke's packages as archives.  And as I say above, he's compiled them against the VS2008 C library, which is what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: The standard ``unzip`` program on my Ubuntu laptop can unpack the zip files.

Comment: @codeape: definitely struggling on Windows!

Comment: I have build my numpy on cygwin. after running `python setup.py build`...  i have taken the 'numpy' dir from build's dir (named as 'lib.cygwin').. .
and its working  perfeclty. I have not installed 'numpy' before(and i am on windows xp) and after importing.. in globals() it shows as ` <module 'numpy' from 'numpy/__init__.py'>`

Comment: @NamitKewat:  I'll give it a try - will need to see if I get any binary incompatibilities.  If not, I'll mark yours as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use cygwin to build numpy on windows.
I am on windows-xp

Its working fine for me.. .!

In cygwin python2.6 comes as a default python. I have installed python2.7 but not installed  numpy in python2.7.

To use it on python2.7 i have run `python2.7 setup.py build` 
You can see that in screen-shot of my terminal. and in folder 'namit' i have placed 'numpy' dir that i have compiled on cygwin. 
when i have imported numpy when i am in that dir.. it worked...you can see that in globals() from where it has imported.

[image]

Comment: Only one clarification - was Python 2.7 installed using the standard install or had you compiled that with cygwin as well?

Comment: i have downloaded python source from its website and installed it like we are doing on unix/linux... .everything was done in cygwin using cygwin's terminal.

Comment: Ah, well, I'll try it, but this is less likely to work as I have to compile Python in VS2010 as I am embedding the interpreter

Comment: This worked perfectly - not sure if it was cygwin or not, but I ended up with a numpy linked against the right c library