# Compiling Numpy with Python 3.2 VS2010

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, numpy

Ive been able to compile Python 3.2 using VS2010, but have had no luck compiling numpy 1.6.2rc1, or even numpy1.7

I am able to compile both Python3.2 and Numpy using VS2008 for example (Both 32 and 64 bit)

Does anyone have any clues if numpy VS2010 is possible or even a more appropriate forum to search?

Thanks.
Rob

Comment: similar solution for numpy is here, its about building numpy source and then using numpy from that built without installing it on windows...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470374/install-numpy-compiled-for-vs2010-for-an-embedded-interpreter/13472077#13472077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile the numpy via MinGW & MinGW64, which using the same runtime as VC++.

I have upload a 64bit numpy 1.6.2 at [SF.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/ray_linn/64bit-libraries/numpy/)